# How do I get maximum document size inside a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to compute a `maxObjSize` inside a specific MongoDB collection. It seems that the `db.collection_name.stats()` returns lots of data, including a `avgObjSize` but not max value for a single row.